# React using Laravel 8 after page refresh creating new Auth session

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-8

I created application React using Laravel 8, I'm using laravel Auth to do a login process and keep my application authenticated using `Auth::check()`, also made changes in session.php using session as database. once user gets login using `Auth::attempt`, If I refresh page, `Auth::check` return false.But If I check with postman or if I hit API of `Auth::check()` in brwoser it return true but not works if refresh page.

**How Do I maintain the Auth session with react using laravel.**

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you have to mention how your using react with laravel or separate

Comment: yes, I am using react with laravel.

Comment: so your using react router or laravel router >

Comment: route calling from reatc router. and api fto check user is logged in or not is written in api.php

Comment: and what middleware your using ?

Comment: Issue resolved by commenting given line from kernel.php -> middlewareGroups -> web    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

Comment: `Auth session` and `VerifyCsrfToken` what is related ?